# Create a combined primary key with a one column accepting NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `CustomerLocation` with the following columns :

- Country
- Region
- City

I want to create a composite primary key with the 3 columns mentioned above knowing that the `Region` column is `NULLABLE`.

Comment: foreign key references are allowed to reference unique constraints in SQL Server as well as primary key constraints (as none of the answers explicitly state this fact)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  The definition of `primary key` specifies that only non-`NULL` values are allowed.  This is clearly explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver15):

> All columns defined within a PRIMARY KEY constraint must be defined as NOT NULL. If nullability is not specified, all columns participating in a PRIMARY KEY constraint have their nullability set to NOT NULL.

That said, the documentation doesn't explain that this is consistent with the SQL standard and the definition of primary keys and `NULL` in all databases.

But I would recommend that you have a single integer key for the table:

```
create table CustomerLocation as (
    CustomerLocationId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    . . .
);
```

You can define a `unique` constraint on the three columns, but foreign key references should use the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a primary key constraint, use a unique constraint to enforce the key because the region attribute allows NULLs, and between the two types of constraints, only the latter allows NULLs :

```
ALTER TABLE CustLocations ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_CustLocations
UNIQUE (country, region, city);
```