# EF Core composed key with one of the fields being nullable

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have an entity with the following fields:

```
public Guid FirstId { get; private set; }
public Guid? SecondId { get; private set; }
```

And I want to configure it to use a composed key with those fields:

```
entity
    .HasKey(e => new { e.FirstId, e.SecondId })
    .IsClustered(false)
    .HasName("MyKey");

entity
    .Property(e => e.SecondId)
    .IsRequired(false);
```

But my `SecondId` field is nullable, so when I try to add a new migration I got an error telling me that it's not possible to create a key where one of the fields is nullable, so there is no way to create a composed key where one of the fields could be null? Do you see any solution?

I'm using Entity Framework Core 7.

Comment: I think this is relational databases FK constraint limitation/requirement, hence EF Core cannot do anything about it.

Comment: It starts with that not being possible at the database level. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61822751/create-a-combined-primary-key-with-a-one-column-accepting-null) for SQL Server. You'll find similar for other databases.

Comment: Have you tried to create such table using database tools without EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you **Ivan** and **pfx**, as **pfx** said this operation is not possible at the database level, there is nothing that EF Core can do. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61822751/create-a-combined-primary-key-with-a-one-column-accepting-null) that **pfx** brought shows it.

---

**But** I could solve the problem using an **Unique Index** instead of **Primary Key**, like that:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  FirstId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
  SecondId uniqueidentifier NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex ON MyTable (FirstId, SecondId);
```

And those are my regiters:

```
FirstId                                 SecondId    
456D8179-F79A-46DC-811D-2DEECF710C9D    NULL
456D8179-F79A-46DC-811D-2DEECF710C9D    8DFAA4A8-D035-4137-92AE-94472361EDE4
456D8179-F79A-46DC-811D-2DEECF710C9D    242BE9E2-EB01-433E-AE40-AE8822F89493
456D8179-F79A-46DC-811D-2DEECF710C9D    4A8C3463-5BA4-42E7-A44A-B56B829953BC
08A8881E-CA7C-4720-95CA-D5571BFC112D    NULL
08A8881E-CA7C-4720-95CA-D5571BFC112D    CF3C3283-CE0E-4CFF-9FE8-C9AD55FA54C4
```

---

Using EF Core would be like that:

```
entity
    .HasIndex(e => new { e.FirstId, e.SecondId })
    .IsUnique()
    .IsClustered(false)
    .HasName("MyIndex");

entity
    .Property(e => e.SecondId)
    .IsRequired(false);
```